# CPLEX OPL massy code error

Tags: cplex, opl

I used *IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio* to run a MILProblem, but got an error with massy code. The file editor didn't alert any errors until I pushed the run button.

The error is

```
ÔËÐÐÅäÖá°option 1¡±²»´æÔڡ£          unknown OPL
```

As such an error, I really don't know how to google it. Here is the .mod and .dat file.

.mod file

```
    {string} prd = ...;
int NP = ...;//number of periods
range T = 0..NP;
int Inventory[prd] = ...;
int purchase[prd] = ...;

int sl = ...;
int sm = ...;
float cl = ...;
float cm = ...;
float hR = ...;
float hI = ...;
float cB = ...;
int demand[prd][1..NP] = ...;
int buy[prd][T] = ...;
int inv[prd][T] = ...;
int u[prd] = ...;
int lb = ...;
int ubl = ...;
int ubm = ...;

dvar int+ Y[prd][T];
dvar int+ X[prd][T];
dvar int+ raw[prd][T];
dvar int+ backlog[prd][T];
dvar boolean L[prd][T];
dvar boolean M[prd][T];


minimize
    sum(p in prd, t in T)
        (sl*L[p][t] + sm*M[p][t] + cl*Y[p][t] + cm*X[p][t] + 
        hR*raw[p][t] + hI*inv[p][t] + cB*backlog[p][t]);

subject to {
    forall(p in prd, t in T)
        ctraw:
            raw[p][t] + (X[p][t] + Y[p][t])*u[p] == buy[p][t] + raw[p][t-1] ;
    forall(p in prd, t in T)
        ctInventory:
            inv[p][t] + buy[p][t-1] + demand[p][t] == X[p][t] + Y[p][t] + inv[p][t-1] + buy[p][t] ;
    forall(p in prd, t in T)
      ctYub:
        Y[p][t] <= ubl*L[p][t];
    forall(p in prd, t in T)
      ctYlb:
        Y[p][t] >= lb*L[p][t];
    forall(p in prd, t in T)
      ctXub:
        X[p][t] <= ubm*M[p][t];
    forall(p in prd, t in T)
      ctYcapacity:
        sum(p in prd)
          Y[p][t] <= ubl;
    forall(p in prd, t in T)
      ctXcapacity:
        sum(p in prd)
            X[p][t] <= ubm;
    forall( p in prd )
      ctInitialInventory:
        inv[p][0] == Inventory[p]; inv[prd][0]
    forall( p in prd )
      ctInitialBuy:
        buy[p][0] == purchase[p];
};
```

.dat file

```
    prd = {A B C D E F G H I};
NP = 52;
demand = #[
...
]#;

buy = #[
...
]#;

Inventory = #[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]#;
purchase = #[2900 500 2400 900 500 30 800 20 150]#;
u = #[0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.05 0.09 0.09 0.09]#;
sl = 1500;
sm = 500;
cl = 0.225;
cm = 0.5;
hR = 0.05;
hI = 0.01;
cB = 0.1;
lb = 1000;
ubl = 8000;
ubm = 2500;
```

Comment: If I just paste that code into the editor, it highlights an error immediately. What is the extra code on the end of line 61 supposed to be? Is that just a typo while pasting your code here?

Comment: It is a typo. But even if I remove the code after the semicolon `;` I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

.dat

```
demand = [];
buy = [];
inv=[];
```

and .mod

you also need some fixes.

For example try

```
forall(p in prd, t in T:t-1 in T)
```

when you need to use t-1.

regards

Comment: I've checked my codes carefully and find some mistakes, but the reason for this messy code error is that my cplex is Promotional version  which limits at most 1000 constraints. what's worse is the error display also encountered an encoding problem (my locale is Chinese). When I used command line to operate cplex, it showed this error. `Promotional version. Problem size limits exceeded`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Chinese version Studio, try to set everything into English including the file names, the configuration names and the directory. There are several encoding problems in the studio.